# Compare varchar with char

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

I am trying to figure out what Postgres does when comparing `varchar` with `char`.

Here is one of my tests:

```
test=# select 'a'::character varying = 'a     '::character;
?column?
----------
 t

test=# select 'ab'::character varying = 'ab     '::character;
?column?
----------
 f
```

This looks like a bug to me. Does anyone know what is going on here? Are there good documents on this topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a bug at all.
Casting the string literal `'ab     '` to `character`, this is what you get:

```
a
```

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html)

> `character` without length specifier is equivalent to `character(1)`.

`'a'::character(1)` will then be coerced to `varchar` (`character varying`) to test for equality with `'a'::varchar` or `'ab'::varchar` and yield `TRUE` or `FALSE` respectively.

Basically, there is hardly any good reason to use `character` *at all*. It's a legacy type that has outlived its usefulness. Just use `text` or `varchar`.

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Comment: "Basically, there is hardly any good reason to use" --- aren't fixed length rows more efficient (for lookups)?

Comment: @zerkms not for Postgres. "While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. " http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-character.html