# Get sum of integers for UNIQUE ids

Tags: postgresql, join, database-design, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

In a game using PostgreSQL 9.3 as backend I am trying to limit the number of games played by a user per week.

I have prepared [an SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b8eba/3), but unfortunately it doesn't work.

My (test, not production) code is here:

```
create table pref_users (
        id varchar(32) primary key,
        last_ip inet
);

create table pref_match (
        id varchar(32) references pref_users on delete cascade,
        completed integer default 0 check (completed >= 0),
        yw char(7) default to_char(current_timestamp, 'IYYY-IW'),
        primary key(id, yw)
);
```

And here is a stored procedure with which I try to find the number of games played this week:

```
create or replace function pref_get_user_info(
    IN _id varchar,
    IN _last_ip inet,
    OUT games_this_week integer
) as $BODY$
        begin
            select sum(completed)
            into games_this_week
            from pref_match where
            (id = _id or
            id in (select id from pref_users where last_ip=_last_ip)) and
            yw=to_char(current_timestamp, 'IYYY-IW');
        end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

With this condition:

```
(id = _id or
 id in (select id from pref_users where last_ip=_last_ip))
```

I am trying to catch users who will try to cheat and join the game with a different player `id` but from the same IP-address.

But I am worried, that sometimes I will get doubled number of completed games - because in the above condition first the 1st part will match: `id = _id` and then the 2nd part `id in (...)` - and this will give me the number of games 2 times.

Is there please any cure for that?

I need to "detect" when an `id` is used twice in the above condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Table layout

Do not use `char(7)` to store a timestamp.

To be precise, do not use `char(7)` to store *anything*. Ever. Details:
[Compare varchar with char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333196/compare-varchar-with-char/17333258#17333258)

And do not store date / time data in *any* text representation. Use [`timestamp` or `date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html).

If you are only interested in the *week of the year*, you could just store an `integer` (or even a `smallint`), which you get with with [extract()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
SELECT extract(week FROM now())::int;
```

But I suggest to store a `date` which occupies 4 bytes, just like an `integer`, while `char(7)` occupies 11 bytes. You can extract the week with above function cheaply. Or use [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', now())
```

And `id` should much rather be `int` - or `bigint` if you must. `varchar(32)` is rather inefficient.

And declare your column `completed` `NOT NULL`! Or you'd have to deal with possible NULL values. Your check constraint does *not* cover that. NULL does not violate the constraint.

#### Query / function

Assuming data type `date` for `yw` and `int` for `id`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pref_get_user_info(_id int, _last_ip inet
            ,OUT games_this_week int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _this_monday date := date_trunc('week', now())::date;
BEGIN

   SELECT sum(completed)::int
   INTO   games_this_week
   FROM   pref_users u
   JOIN   pref_match m USING (id)
   WHERE (u.id = _id OR u.last_ip = _last_ip)
   AND    m.yw BETWEEN _this_monday
                   AND _this_monday + 6;  -- "sargable"

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If `last_ip` was defined `NOT NULL`, you would not need `_id` as parameter at all. Just `_last_ip`.

Comment: Thanks - I know, that I should have used a timestamp and not string, but I made that wrong decision 4 years ago, can't change the database now... And why do you suggest to add `NOT NULL` to `completed`? Doesn't `default 0` suffice?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: If you want to make sure a column is never NULL, define it `NOT NULL`. A default is not enough - one can still enter NULL this way. Also helps storage and query planning.

Answer (score 1):

I would tried some sort of pivot table, although i don't know if plpgsql supports it.

```
begin
    select 
    SUM
    (
        CASE WHEN pref_match.id IN (select id from pref_users where last_ip=_last_ip)
        THEN completed
    ) AS ip_matches,
    SUM
    (
        CASE WHEN pref_match.id = _id
        THEN completed
    ) AS id_matches,
    into games_this_week
    from pref_match
    and yw=to_char(current_timestamp, 'IYYY-IW');
end;
```

Then get max of two values.

But one user can play from more than 1 IP, this is not covered here (most probably you need to log every game IP to catch those situtations)

Also note, that this is will be VERY low-perfomance code. The subquery will run on every matched row at filter stage.