# ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, return-type

Building on these tables:

```
create table f1_driver(
 code varchar(5) not null primary key,
 name varchar(10),
 surname varchar(20),
 dateofbirth date,
 debut integer,
 countryoforigin varchar(20),
 points integer
);

create table f1_results (
 drivercode varchar(5) not null references f1_driver,
 circuitcode varchar(5) not null references f1_circuit,
 racedate date,
 raceposition integer,
 grid integer,
 primary key (drivercode, circuitcode,  racedate)
);
```

I want to make a function that the user will give the `circuitcode` and the function will return the `name` and `surname` of the drivers that in this specific circuit the `raceposition` was better than the `grid`.

I write this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get(character) RETURNS SETOF f1_driver AS
$$
SELECT  D.name, D.surname
FROM f1_driver D,f1_results R
WHERE R.circuitcode = $1
AND D.code=R.drivercode
AND R.raceposition<grid ;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And I have this error:

> ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return f1_driver
> DETAIL:  Final statement returns too few columns.
> CONTEXT:  SQL function "get"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row type `f1_driver` does not match what you actually return. Use [**`RETURNS TABLE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) to provide a matching declaration:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_get_drivers(varchar)
  RETURNS TABLE(name varchar, surname varchar) AS
$func$
SELECT D.name, D.surname
FROM   f1_driver D
JOIN   f1_results R ON R.drivercode = D.code
WHERE  R.circuitcode = $1
AND    R.raceposition < R.grid;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

#### Major points

- The declared return type in `RETURNS` must match what's actually returned.
- <strike>`character`</strike> was the wrong data type for your input parameter. Use `text` or `varchar`. Details:

  - [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)
  - [Compare varchar with char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333196/compare-varchar-with-char/17333258#17333258)
- Use an explicit `JOIN` doing the same. That's easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return integer
> DETAIL:  Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING.
> CONTEXT:  SQL function "my_func"

Because I used `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` to create a transaction in the [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
START TRANSACTION; -- Here
  SELECT 2;
COMMIT; -- Here
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

So instead, I used [BEGIN ATOMIC ... END statement](https://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/detail/393/) as shown below, then the error was solved. *`BEGIN ATOMIC ... END` statement works only for a [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) but not for a [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) according to [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) and you can unset `LANGUAGE SQL` when using `BEGIN ATOMIC ... END` statement but it is still a SQL function and the function in PostgreSQL is already in a single transaction by default so I don't need to create a transaction in them:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
  SELECT 2;
END;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER /* LANGUAGE SQL */
BEGIN ATOMIC
  SELECT 2;
END;
```