# Function shows error "relation my_table does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql, search-path

I created a function to generate invoice numbers but when I do:

```
select get_generated_kodesj()
```

it shows an error:

> relation "transpending_h" does not exist
>   LINE 19: ...END END END AS "KODETRANSNEW" FROM transpendi...

Here my function declaration:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_generated_kodesj()
RETURNS CHAR AS $$
DECLARE kodeSJ CHAR;
BEGIN      
        SELECT
        CASE WHEN MAX(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4)) IS NULL THEN
        CONCAT('SJ-',EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()),LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from NOW()) AS CHAR), 2 ,'0'),'0001')
        ELSE
        CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4) AS INTEGER))+1<10 THEN
        CONCAT('SJ-',EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()),LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from NOW()) AS CHAR), 2 ,'0'),'000',
        MAX(CAST(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4) AS INTEGER))+1)
        ELSE
        CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4) AS INTEGER))+1<100 AND MAX(CAST(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4) AS INTEGER))+1>=10 THEN
        CONCAT('SJ-',EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()),LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from NOW()) AS CHAR), 2 ,'0'),'00',
        MAX(CAST(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4) AS INTEGER))+1)
        ELSE 
        CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4) AS INTEGER))+1<1000 AND MAX(CAST(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4) AS INTEGER))+1>=100 THEN
        CONCAT('SJ-',EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()),LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from NOW()) AS CHAR), 2 ,'0'),'0',
        MAX(CAST(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4) AS INTEGER))+1)
        ELSE 
        CONCAT('SJ-',EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()),LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from NOW()) AS CHAR), 2 ,'0'),
        MAX(CAST(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4) AS INTEGER))+1)
        END END END END AS "KODETRANSNEW" INTO kodeSJ
        FROM transpending_h
        WHERE SUBSTRING("KODETRANS" FROM 5 FOR 4)=CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR from NOW()) AS CHAR)
        AND SUBSTRING("KODETRANS" FROM 9 FOR 2)=CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from NOW()) AS CHAR);
    RETURN kodeSJ;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY DEFINER
    -- Set a secure search_path: trusted schema(s), then 'pg_temp'.
    SET search_path = admin, pg_temp;
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: I assume you're sure the relation `transpending_h` does exist in the current schema. Right?

Comment: but i already created this table, and before i declared this function, i run this query (select something), it works.

Comment: I see. Well, syntactically your function is just fine. Double check if you're not executing query and function in different schemata / different databases. Good luck!

Comment: security definer means you want to run this `fn()` with some other user, not the fn() creator - right? does that other user has the schema where `transpending_h` locates in his `search_path`?..

Comment: You are using case-sensitive column names (`"KODETRANS"` is a different name than `KODETRANS`) maybe your table was created all uppercase as well? So you need to use `from "TRANSPENDING_H"`

Comment: for all fields i did with uppercase but tables name i did lowercase

Answer (score 1):

You commented:

> but i already created this table, and before i declared this function, i run this query (select something), it works.

You created the table, but obviously not in the schema `admin`, which is the only one in the custom `search_path` of your function (besides the temp schema and the implicit `pg_catalog`). Check:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = 'transpending_h';
```

Schema-qualify the table in the function body and the error should go away. Like: `myschema.transpending_h`.

Related:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)
- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

### Asides

- You operate with the data type `char`, which is a misunderstanding:

  - [Compare varchar with char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333196/compare-varchar-with-char/17333258#17333258)

  Use `text` instead.
- Don't use double-quoted identifiers at all if you can avoid it. Just introduces overhead and confusion.

  - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- You do not need plpgsql for this simple `SELECT`. I suggest a plain SQL function.

On a closer look, ***almost everything*** about your function can be improved. Basically, you are incrementing per-month serial numbers. Could be simplified to something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_generated_kodesj()
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
   SELECT to_char(now(), '"SJ-"YYYYMM')
       || COALESCE(to_char(MAX(RIGHT("KODETRANS",4))::int + 1, 'FM0000'), '0001')
   FROM   transpending_h
   WHERE  "KODETRANS" LIKE to_char(now(), '"SJ-"YYYYMM"%"')
                        -- assuming your codes start with "SJ-"; else adapt
$func$  LANGUAGE sql
        SECURITY DEFINER
        SET search_path = admin, pg_temp;
```

Related:

- [Remove blank-padding from to_char() output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242202/remove-blank-padding-from-to-char-output/22242593#22242593)

But the whole approach still suffers from race conditions in a multi-user environment. Use a global `serial` or `IDENTITY` column (in combination with a `date` or `timestamp`) instead of trying to create your own per-month serial. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)
- [Custom SERIAL / autoincrement per group of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571125/custom-serial-autoincrement-per-group-of-values/34572959#34572959)

If you *need* per-month serial numbers, consider a different approach to avoid race conditions in multi-user environments:

- [How to perform conditional insert based on row count?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167273/how-to-perform-conditional-insert-based-on-row-count/167283#167283)